# How to count the occurrency of a specific character in a list that contains sub-lists of strings?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I would need help regarding this problem. I am trying to loop the index of an element, I have a list which is made of these sub lists: `['Galagonya', 'Alfonz', 'XXXXXXN']`, I am trying to count the number of `"X"`-s in the whole list, so I made a for loop which goes through the big lists 2nd elements(0-1-2), where these letters are, and then I would like to individually check the six characters if they are `"X"` or not, if yes add one to my counter. Code attached. `datum_nelkul` is the big list. Please help me understand how I can improve this code. I get string index out of ranger error.

.

## The non-working one:

```
counter = 0

i = 0

for line in datum_nelkul:
if line[2][i] == "X":
     counter += 1
i +=1
```

## The working one, which only suits short, copiable amounts, but works in this case

```
counter = 0

for line in datum_nelkul:
    if line[2][0] == "X":
        counter += 1
    if line[2][1] == "X":
        counter += 1
    if line[2][2] == "X":
        counter += 1
    if line[2][3] == "X":
        counter+= 1
    if line[2][4] == "X":
        counter += 1
    if line[2][5] == "X":
        counter += 1
    if line[2][6] == "X":
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Not sure I am following your question, but you might just need something like `sum(line[2].count('X') for line in datum_nelkul)`

Comment: So do you want a count of the number of time x occurs in the entire master list?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine with the .count function now.

Comment: I'm going to suggest a title edit to make this post more easily searchable. Good first post though, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate everything and do a count, if I understand how you are trying to count.

```
master_list=[['XXXXXX','a','b','c'],['XXXXXX','a','b','c'],['XXXXXX','a','b','c']]

master_string=''

for l in master_list:
    temp_str=''
    for string in l:
           temp_str+=string
    master_string+=temp_str

x_count=master_string.count('X')

Out: 18
```

Or if you are trying to find the number of X's in each substring, and save those in a list or something

```
master_list=[['XXXXXX','a','b','c'],['XXXXXX','a','b','c'],['XXXXXX','a','b','c']]

x_sublist_counts=[]

for l in master_list:
    temp_str=''
    for string in l:
           temp_str+=string
    x_sublist_counts.append(temp_str.count('X'))

print(x_sublist_counts)

Out: [6, 6, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following one liner. Here you loop over each element of each list in your master list, then you count the occurrences of your letter in that particular element. This will results in a list of integers that corresponds to the number of occurrences that you can simply `sum()` to find the total number of occurrences.

```
x_count = sum([ master_string.count('X') for sub_list in master_list for master_string in sub_list ])
```

Comment: This solution is very nice looking. I tested both and found that for a list of 1000 sublists in the format of my master list my code is actually quit a bit faster, on my machine anyhow. I get 537 microseconds per loop on this answer, and 335 microseconds on mine. So your answer seems to be the most parsimonious, but mine is better for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are iterable in python. All you need to do is something like this :

```
for line in datum_nelkul:
    for c in line[2]:
        if c == "X":
            counter += 1
```